# EF7 Reverse Engineering Tool Does Not Add the StringLength DataAnnotation Automatically

Tags: reverse-engineering, entity-framework-core

I am using the EF7 (Beta8) reverse engineering tool to generate the POCO classes (with DataAnnotations) from the existing database but the generated POCOs don't have the StringLength annotation for the string properties therefore when I apply the migration to an empty database all of the string fields are generated as Nvarchar(MAX) in the tables.

Am I missing something or it is a bug in the reverse engineering tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a feature that had not yet been implemented. It is in the nightly builds and will be in the next release of EF.

See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/commit/6857728ad5691906d859e2835a9ac4917854ce8a

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I look forward to the next release.